# how can I check in my app that letter was sent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendmail, sendgrid

I have a small app which send email. For sending email I use SendGrid. I have a form where a user enters (to, from, subject, body). everything works fine and emails are sent.  But how can I check in my app that letter was sent?

config/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
host = 'localhost:3000'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
 :port           => '587',
 :authentication => :plain,
 :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
 :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
 :domain         => 'gmail.com',
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

app/mailers/send_email.rb

```
class SendMail < ApplicationMailer

 def welcome(from, to, subject, body)
   @greeting = body

   mail from: from, to: to, subject: subject
 end
end
```

app/controllers/send_email_controllers.rb

```
SendMail.welcome(@from, @to, @subject, @body).deliver_now
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can't, really. ruby doesn't deliver email, it just hands it off to a mail server. e.g. it's the equivalent of walking your envelope down to the mailbox on the street corner and tossing it into the slot. after that, ruby's job is done. if you want to confirm delivery, you'll have to set the SMTP delivery confirmation headers, and HOPE that the recipient allows the return receipt notice.

Comment: It's been a while since I used SendGrid, but does it have a webhook or an API that you can use to confirm whether they sent it out?

Comment: Thank you,  I will try Event Webhook for cheking.

Comment: Yeah all you need is [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html)